# Array changes after the corresponding array holding its value changes.

Tags: javascript, angular

I am facing a problem and I am not being able to understand it. I have an service array:

```
this.awesombarservice.Selected = [{id:1, value="20180101"}],[{id:1, value="20180103"}]
```

I have initialise another array and kept the same value like:

```
var this.awesombarservice.filter= this.awesombarservice.Selected
```

so if the made any changes in `this.awesombarservice.filter` that change is reflected in the other array (`this.awesombarservice.Selected`) too . 
What might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

> What might be the problem

You are setting the reference value of `this.awesombarservice.Selected` to `this.awesombarservice.filter`, so both the variables point to the same array now.

However, if you want to make a **deep-copy** of `this.awesombarservice.Selected` then use

```
this.awesombarservice.filter = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.awesombarservice.Selected ) ) )
```

Comment: Ya it worked perfectly . Thank u

Comment: @UdG Glad it worked, please accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.

Comment: @gurvinder372 OP can't upvote.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve this is to use JSON stringify.

```
this.awesombarservice.filter = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.awesombarservice.Selected)
```